# Simple: Adding index to a Java array

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

I'm currently learning Java and refreshing what I've previously learn t, I'm making a quick test array in this class but want to add an index onto the array so the output has a number for the peanuts left.
so ideally the array would start at 5 and count down.

I remember it being a few lines of code, but what those are.... has escaped me.

```
 public class Testing123 {

     public static void main(String[] args){

         String p = " Peanuts left in the jar.";


         int[] anArray = new int[5];

         for(int i=0; i<anArray.length; ++i){
             int index = 0;
             System.out.println(anArray[i] + p);
             ++index;

         }

     }


 }
```

Comment: Where are you "filling values" for anArray ?. Also your i is same as yout index. No point in keeping 2 variables in the loop doing the same job.

Comment: What is the purpose of using an array?

Comment: can you give us your expected output?

Comment: what on earth are you doing with the `index` variable?  It is not even being used.

Comment: Please add index =0 outside the for loop

Comment: Thank you for the replies.. I was just testing with the int index. The reason I'm trying to make it non explicit is so I could make a 1000 index array etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not simplify to

```
public static void main(String[] args){

     String p = " Peanuts left in the jar.";

     int i = 5;
     while (i-- > 0){
         System.out.println(i + p);
     }

 }
```

or if you really want an array

```
int index = 5;
for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; ++i)
{
        anArray[i] = index--;
        System.out.println(anArray[i] + p);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this..

```
 public class Testing123 {

 public static void main(String[] args){

     String p = " Peanuts left in the jar.";


     int[] anArray = new int[5];

     for(int i=(anArray.length -1); i >= 0; --i){

         System.out.println(anArray[i] + p);


     }

 }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
        for (int i = 0; i < anArray.length; ++i)
        {
            anArray[i] = i;
            System.out.println(anArray[i] + p);
        }
```

Comment: Thanks but the questionare doesnt say anything what he expect.

Answer (score 0):

this would work for you:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  String p = " Peanuts left in the jar.";
  int[] anArray = {5,4,3,2,1,0};
  for(int i=0; i<anArray.length; ++i){
      System.out.println(anArray[i] + p);
  }
}
```

Comment: get rid of index will ya.

Comment: i did, it was seconds after i posted that i realized it was still there

Comment: well it has come back, because it is still there - scary ain't it.

Comment: weird, they are out to get me i tell you

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you need to initialize the array.

Secondly, change the for loop.

Also i dont understand the need of index variable.

```
 //int[] anArray = new int[5]; -instead do 
   int[] anArray = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
   for(int i=anArray.length; i>0; i--){
         // int index = 0;  - i dont think you need this..what are you using this for ?
         System.out.println(anArray[i] + p);
         // ++index; - i dont think you need this..what are you using this for ?. 
         //You are initalizing this everytime in the for loop and incrementing. The value will always be 1 or 0.

     }
```